# Recargar Tabs al iniciar sesión Ionic 3, Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

El problema que tengo es el siguiente: para las opciones del menú estoy utilizando tabs, resulta que cuando inicio sesión necesito que se recarguen esas tabs y aparezcan las que correspondan según el tipo de usuario que inicio sesión, ya sea estudiante o profesor. He allí el problema, las tabs al iniciar sesión no se recargan, pero si presiono F5 si aparecen las tabs que le corresponden al usuario. He intentado solucionarlo con eventos pero sin suerte.

Muestro el código que tengo en cada uno de los archivos:

Archivo tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage {

 public sesion:boolean;
 public opt:boolean;
 userDetails:any = {};

 constructor( public events: Events) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('userSesion')) {
   const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSesion'));
   this.userDetails = data;
   if (this.userDetails.tipo == '1') {
    this.opt = false;
   } else {
    this.opt = true;
   }
   this.sesion = true;
 } else {
   this.sesion = false;
 }
}

tab1Root = HomePage;
tab2Root = AboutPage;
tab3Root = ContactPage;
tab4Root = RecuperarclavePage;
tab5Root = EstatusestudiantePage;

tab6Root = InicioPage;
tab7Root = CarrerasestudiantePage;
tab8Root = HistoricoPage;
tab9Root = RecuperarclavePage;
tab10Root = IniciodocentePage;
tab11Root = RecuperarclavePage;
tab12Root = RecuperarclavePage;
tab13Root = RecuperarclavePage;

}
```

Archivo tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs color="primary" *ngIf="!opt">
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Entrar" tabIcon="home" md="md-home" *ngIf="!sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Olvide mi clave" tabIcon="unlock" md="md-unlock" *ngIf="!sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Estatus" tabIcon="search" md="md-search" *ngIf="!sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Ver" tabIcon="search" md="md-search" *ngIf="!sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Ver2" tabIcon="search" md="md-search" *ngIf="!sesion"></ion-tab>

 <ion-tab [root]="tab6Root" tabTitle="Inicio" tabIcon="home" md="md-home" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab7Root" tabTitle="Registro de Inscripción" tabIcon="clipboard" ios="ios-clipboard" md="md-clipboard" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab8Root" tabTitle="Historial Academico" tabIcon="paper" ios="ios-paper" md="md-paper" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab9Root" tabTitle="Inscripción" tabIcon="create" ios="ios-create" md="md-create" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs color="primary" *ngIf="opt">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab10Root" tabTitle="Inicio" tabIcon="home" md="md-home" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab11Root" tabTitle="Carga Academica" tabIcon="unlock" md="md-unlock" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab12Root" tabTitle="Horarios" tabIcon="time" ios="ios-time" md="md-time" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab13Root" tabTitle="Inscritos" tabIcon="clipboard" ios="ios-clipboard" md="md-clipboard" *ngIf="sesion"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Lo que estoy buscando es que al iniciar sesión me muestre las tabs correspondientes al tipo de usuario que inicio sesión, he intentado varias cosas ya pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría un Event https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ .

Al hacer login disparas el publish y te suscribes en la pagina donde tienes los tabs.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que te interesa es que, cada vez que ingreses a aquella pantalla y que las cargue, un buen método es que en el ciclo de **ionViewDidEnter** coloque la logica correspondiente de los datos deseados (asumiendo que siempre poseerás algún dato al iniciar, sino puedes pedirlos)
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Otro posible modo sería usar un observable que, cuando recibas el usuario este se suscriba y se cargue los datos correspondientes.Al hacer esto, cada vez que recibas datos de cualquier usuario, *recarguen esas tabs.*